# jQuery mobile listview doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm am working on a phonegap app for android.
Ofcourse I work with jQuery mobile. At this moment I have made a navbar with 3 tabs,
and when I change the tab, de content changes without reloading the navbar. I use
a seperate javascript to change the content.

But now I'm working on a listview, like u see in the jQuery mobile demo's.
The problem is that this doesn't work. You don't see a "application like listitem", 
but you see a dot with the listitemname, a html listitem without any css.

The listview is in the "page_zoek_category" and inside that there is a "content_zoek_category" and inside that you can find the listview "list_category"

My html script:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_main">
  <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
          <li><a id="tab_home" href="#" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a id="tab_zoek" href="#" >Zoek</a></li>
          <li><a id="tab_scan" href="#" >Scan</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content" id="content_main">
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page_home">
  <div data-role="content" id="content_home">
    home
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page_zoek_category">
  <div data-role="content" id="content_zoek_category">
      <ul data-role="listview" id="list_category" data-inset="true">
          <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page_zoek_detail">
  <div data-role="content" id="content_zoek_detail">
      zoek_detail
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page_scan">
  <div data-role="content" id="content_scan">
      scan
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my javascript file

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#content_main').html($('#content_home').html());

    $("#tab_home").click(function () {
        $('#content_main').html($('#content_home').html());
    });

    $("#tab_zoek").click(function () {
        $('#content_main').html($('#content_zoek_category').html());
    });

    $("#tab_scan").click(function () {
        $('#content_main').html($('#content_scan').html());
    });
});
```

Comment: how do you update listview?

Comment: At this moment it is a static listview with one listview item. But because this doesn't work, I'm not going to populate it wit json yet.

Comment: The three lines of code to create this list should work, because I have tried it in a seperate file, but in this script it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
$("#tab_zoek").click(function () {
    $('#content_main').html($('#content_zoek_category').html());
    $('#page_main').trigger( "create");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lu4qw/

2nd way:

```
$("#tab_zoek").click(function () {
    $('#content_main').html($('#content_zoek_category').html());
    $('#list_category').listview().listview("refresh");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lu4qw/1/

Comment: Works like a charm. Another question, is there a reason why the listview isn't the full width of the screen. (is that te page-role="content"?